# При добавлении товара в корзину перебрасывает на другую страницу

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

Всем привет. Есть магазин на wordpress woocommerce. В слайдере магазина вставил ссылку на на добавление товара в корзину с таким содержанием

```
<a href="/shop/?add-to-cart=3410" rel="nofollow" data-product_id="3410" data-product_sku="" data-quantity="1" class="wpb_button wpb_btn-orange wpb_btn-big">Купить!</a>
```

Товар добавляется, все хорошо, но меня почему-то перебрасывает при этом на другую страницу. Почему так? и что нужно сделать, чтобы на ней же остаться?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При щелчке по ссылке, само собой вы будете переходить на другую страницу. Добавление товара у вас реализована через JavaScript? Если так, то в обработке события, вам нужно отменить действия браузера по умолчанию, есть стандартный метод  event.preventDefault().

```
$('a').click(function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();                 
});
```